# Define a collection with some columns PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, procedure

I have to create a collection with 2 fields ,and then to create a procedure having as parameter a variable with that collection's type.
How could I create a collection with 2 fields if I only have :

```
TYPE an_array IS VARRAY(10) OF varchar2(20);
```

For example columns : id, name; (Do not know how to insert them).

And after that, I have to create the procedure ,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (p_array an_array) AS
```

But I have to use my columns to do something in this procedure.
As example , I consider a table employees (id number, name varchar2(20));
My procedure should look like this :

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (p_array an_array) AS
    CURSOR cs IS select * from employees;
    v_row employees%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
    OPEN cs;
    LOOP
    FETCH cs into v_row ;
    EXIT WHEN cs%NOTFOUND;
     IF (mod (v_row.id,2 ) = 0 ) then
        THE ID FIELD FROM MY COLLETION  := v_row.id;
        THE NAME FIELD FROM MY COLLECTION := v_row.name;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cs;
    END;
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a collection of records.

something like this

```
declare
   type TRec is record(
      col_1 varchar2(20),
      col_2 number);

   type TList is table of TRec;

   t_l TList := TList();

   r_l TRec;

   procedure foo(a_par TList, ai_elem int) is
   begin
      if a_par.Exists(ai_elem) then
         dbms_output.put_line('Value at pos ' || ai_elem || ' is :' || a_par(ai_elem)
                              .col_2);
      else
         dbms_output.put_line('There is no element in position :' || ai_elem);
      end if;

   end;

begin
   r_l.col_1 := 'abc';
   r_l.col_2 := 10;

   t_l.Extend;
   t_l(t_l.Count) := r_l;

   foo(t_l, 1);

   foo(t_l, 3);

end;
```

Comment: Alright, but then how would I declare the procedure ? I mean , I have to declare my Record in an anonymous block ,so how to get the collection outside of it ?

Comment: I don't understand clearly , why you "have to declare" types you need in anonymous block. What about visibility scope ? If you declare your types in anonymous block then you have declare your procedure in that block too.

Comment: Yup, that's right, I just have to declare them in the same block,thanks.